# What is the best way to make a java class library in Android with Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I wonder, What is the best way to make a java class library in Android with Eclipse?. I know if I have done well.

1. I created an Android project and indicated that a library project. And without creating any activities.
2. Then I think my classes.
3. I create a folder called "jar"
4. Exporto classes to jar and keep in the "jar" folder.
5. In the projects that I want to add I add this jar as external jar.

This is what I do but I honestly do not know if it is right. The idea is to create general classes and be able to share and maintain it properly for other projects.

Comment: there is a specific notion of library in android that is supported by eclipse. you use the android properties tab of your project, and link the libraries there. due to the resource management in android. compilation in jar may not be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But as I said I do not quite right. But then, what do you think about what I have been advised _red?. And how would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea with a library project is you create classes within it. Then you reference them via your main projects manifest.

Add the library project in the main project settings and you will have general classes that you can share to any project.

I assume this is what you are looking for based on your post.

**Edit**

Here is how to do it:

1) Set project to be library (you have said you have done this).

2) Put your classes in your library project. (So you can call them from other projects).

3) Go to the main project and right click on it, select Android from the settings. This is where you turned your library project, into a library project.

4) Anyway, at the bottom click add.

5) In the manifest, create and activity reference to a class in the library project.

6) So if you are trying to get MainActivity you call com.library.project.package.MainActivity

Now you will have the MainActivity viewing able if you ran the project.

Comment: I appreciate your information. But actually my question is that since no one has taught me how. So my question is What is the correct way to do it?, Okay as I do?

Comment: I have edited my post above.